# Reference projected child component from parent component in Qwik

Tags: qwik

I want to create a `<Breadcrumb>` component in Qwik with a declarative syntax:

```tex
<Breadcrumb>
  <BreadcrumbSegment url="/collections/233...">Tintins äventyr</BreadcrumbSegment>
  <BreadcrumbSegment url="/works/233...">Blå lotus</BreadcrumbSegment>
  <BreadcrumbSegment url="/books/233...">Kinesiska</BreadcrumbSegment>
</Breadcrumb>
```

That generates the following markup when rendered:

```html
<nav aria-label="Breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="/collections/233...">
        Tintins äventyr
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/works/233...">
        Blå lotus
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/books/233..." aria-current="page">
        Kinesiska
      </a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context":"https://schema.org",
   "@type":"BreadcrumbList",
   "itemListElement":[
      {
         "@type":"ListItem",
         "position":1,
         "name":"Tintins äventyr",
         "item":"/collections/233..."
      },
      {
         "@type":"ListItem",
         "position":2,
         "name":"Blå lotus",
         "item":"/collections/233..."
      },
      {
         "@type":"ListItem",
         "position":3,
         "name":"Kinesiska",
         "item":"/books/233..."
      }
   ]
}
</script>
```

To generate that JSON-LD I need to reference those child components from the parent and retrieve its slotted value and URL property, but have not found a straight forward way to achieve this.

I'm reading this from the [Qwik documentation](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/slots/):

> **Note:** Slots in Qwik are declarative, allowing Qwik to render parents and children in isolation. Because slots are declarative, the children can NOT be read, or transformed by the components.

So clearly, there are limitations here. Obviously, I could pass in an array of URLs and names to the `<Breadcrumb>` component, but that's not what I want. I would like to maintain the declarative syntax in the example.

**Conceptually, how would I solve this problem?** I'm new to Qwik (and have limited knowledge of React), so sorry if the answer is obvious.